# Tensorboard: Can a user visualize a computation graph in Tensorboard from Easy Execution or before running a Session?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I know that Tensorboard visualizes the computation graph when the session starts, however I was hoping to use it as a tool to build the computation graph in the first place. I think some people have asked this question before, but have not seen any references to it lately.

I was wondering if there might be a new plugin or extension to Tensorboard that allows a user to interactively build the computation graph, whether this be in eager execution mode or not?